# KKT conditions for quadratic optimization

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Assume the primal problem of:
$$max_x \mu^Tx$$
$$st. x^T\Sigma x\leq \sigma^2$$
$$ Ax=b$$$$ Cx\geq d$$

What is the KKT optimality conditions for this?

So far this is what I got:
$$L(x,\lambda,w,v)= -\mu^Tx+\lambda^T(x^{T}\Sigma x-\sigma^2))-w^T(cx-d)+v^T(b-Ax)$$
$$x^{*T}\Sigma x^*\leq\sigma^2$$
$$-Cx^*\leq -d$$
$$Ax^*=b$$
$$\lambda^*\geq 0$$
$$w^*\geq 0$$
$$\lambda^T(x^{*T}\sigma x^*-\sigma^2)=0$$
$$w^T(Cx^*-d)=0$$
$$\nabla (-\mu^Tx^*)+\lambda^T(\nabla(x^{*T}\Sigma x^*-\sigma^2))-w^T(\nabla(cx^*-d))+v^T (\nabla(b-Ax^*))=0$$
Is this correct? How should I solve the last equation?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Were you able to write down the Lagrangian? Chapter 5 of Boyd and Vandenberghe (which is free online) is a very helpful resource for learning about the KKT conditions and the dual problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and post my progress. Just a question (might sound really stupid!) but does it make any difference that it's a maximization?@littleO

Comment: Yes, the KKT conditions and the dual problem are usually presented with the assumption that we're minimizing a convex function, and we do need to be careful about that. In this case, you can reformulate your problem as minimizing $-\mu^T x$ subject to the given constraints. If $x^\star$ is optimal for the original problem, then $x^\star$ is optimal for the reformulated problem, and vice versa.

Comment: The third equation should be $-Cx^* \le -d$.  
Depending if your problem is a min or max problem, the signs of the dual variables will be different.